# PHP SOAP Salesforce Sub Query

Tags: php, arrays, salesforce

I am using SOAP to query our Salesforce database and can query and display the results. However i now want to use relationship queries (sub queries). I can get results from the query, but struggling to displaythe sub query results in PHP.

I am doing the following:

```
$Query = "SELECT Account.Name, (SELECT Contact.Name, Contact.accountId FROM contacts) FROM Account WHERE Name Like '%Test Client%'";
    $Response = $SforceConnection->query($Query);

    foreach ($Response->records as $RecordSet) {
    echo "$RecordSet->Name."<br />";
    }
```

I can display the company name just fine, but struggling to display the sub query data like the Contact.Name and Contact.accountId. i am not sure of the correct syntax to display these 2 fields.

When i run the SQL i get the following Array repose:

```
["queryLocator"]=> NULL ["done"]=> bool(true) ["records"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#10 (3) { 
        ["Id"]=> NULL ["Contacts"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (4) { 
            ["done"]=> bool(true) ["queryLocator"]=> NULL ["records"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> object(stdClass)#12 (3) { 
                    ["Id"]=> NULL ["AccountId"]=> string(18) "0015800000UU25zAER" ["Name"]=> string(16) "Test Users" } 
                } 

            ["size"]=> int(1) 
        } ["Name"]=> string(15) "Test Client" 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the contacts in the following way:

```
if (isset($RecordSet->Contacts) && isset($RecordSet->Contacts->records) && !empty($RecordSet->Contacts->records)) {
  foreach($RecordSet->Contacts->records as $contact) {
    echo $contact->Name;
  }
}
```